# How do you add StreamSocketListener to Unity 3D UWP app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

We are constructing our first Windows UWP app that uses StreamSocketListener class.   In Unity, we have configured the project to have networking capabilities.

When we try to compile, VS.NET states that networking related classes can't be found.

I appreciate recommendations to help resolve this "references/capabilities" problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your Package.appxmanifest and navigate to the Capabilities tab and make sure you selected Internet (Client & Sever) assuming you require outbound access to the Internet.